# Font of section/subsection different than font of main text?

Tags: fonts, sectioning

Why is the font of my sections, subsections and so on different than the font of my main text?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=13pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}



\begin{document}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed lorem sodales, commodo felis nec, feugiat leo. Ut non erat enim. Etiam at mi ut metus ullamcorper interdum. Nam non aliquet dolor. Aliquam varius arcu eu tempor pellentesque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Duis ut egestas turpis, maximus dictum urna.

\section{Introduction}

Nunc vitae libero ac tortor sagittis auctor. Morbi iaculis, lacus pretium porta aliquam, lorem lorem lobortis felis, tristique condimentum elit nibh vel nunc. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque pellentesque orci vel lectus placerat, et tempor nisi faucibus.

\section{Chapter}

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus eleifend consequat magna nec tincidunt. Donec et tortor erat. Phasellus iaculis rutrum orci, sit amet dapibus augue fringilla viverra. Ut dapibus risus magna, eget sodales quam condimentum quis.

\subsection{Subsection}

In ut elit in risus tristique eleifend eu sed est. Etiam suscipit lacinia semper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Quisque et ex augue. Fusce eu arcu semper, cursus sem tincidunt, convallis augue. Vestibulum consectetur neque nec velit efficitur, sit amet consectetur purus finibus. Sed a pharetra eros.


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a precise choice of the class author. You can change the font for titles to be the same font family as the main text in various ways, one is as follows.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=13pt,egregdoesnotlikesansseriftitles]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[english, main=ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{aligned-overset}



\begin{document}

 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec sed lorem sodales, commodo felis nec, feugiat leo. Ut non erat enim. Etiam at mi ut metus ullamcorper interdum. Nam non aliquet dolor. Aliquam varius arcu eu tempor pellentesque. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Duis ut egestas turpis, maximus dictum urna.

\section{Introduction}

Nunc vitae libero ac tortor sagittis auctor. Morbi iaculis, lacus pretium porta aliquam, lorem lorem lobortis felis, tristique condimentum elit nibh vel nunc. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Quisque pellentesque orci vel lectus placerat, et tempor nisi faucibus.

\section{Chapter}

In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus eleifend consequat magna nec tincidunt. Donec et tortor erat. Phasellus iaculis rutrum orci, sit amet dapibus augue fringilla viverra. Ut dapibus risus magna, eget sodales quam condimentum quis.

\subsection{Subsection}

In ut elit in risus tristique eleifend eu sed est. Etiam suscipit lacinia semper. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Quisque et ex augue. Fusce eu arcu semper, cursus sem tincidunt, convallis augue. Vestibulum consectetur neque nec velit efficitur, sit amet consectetur purus finibus. Sed a pharetra eros.


\end{document}
```

Another way is to state, in the document preamble,

```
\setkomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\bfseries}
```

which is as cryptic as it could be.

<sub>I once said in an answer here that there should be an option to get titles in the standard family and the class author's action was to add the option you see at the top.</sub>

A couple of notes: you should also do

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

or German would not be correctly hyphenated. You should also do

```
\usepackage{fix-cm}
```

if you want to use 13pt font size (which is *very* large, anyway).

[image]

Comment: +1 for suggesting the highly informative document class option!

Comment: @Mico The option should be `markuskohmlikesseriftitlesbutnoteverybodyelsedoes`

Comment: @egreg Awesome answer and explanations! Thank you very much.